# XAMPP shows error for .exe from non-local domains

Tags: url, http-status-code-404, localhost, xampp

In FireFox3 when I go to URL's such as:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/A/A/4AA524C6-239D-47FF-860B-5B397199CBF8/windows-kb890830-v2.7.exe

I get a 404 error for the URL locally on my XAMPP installation I use for local development.

It has to do with the .exe I think but I can't figure out why.

Whats the problem?

Object not found!

---

ERROR:

---

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
download.microsoft.com
02/12/09 15:47:20
Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.5

Comment: If you're downloading executables directly from urls there is no limit to what could have installed itself on your machine.

Comment: In firefox it prompts you to download first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by a root kit.

Answer (score 0):

Are the xampp services running when the error occurs?

Comment: Yes they are running 24/7, but I have just started to notice this.